# Condition lead results in postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `person_updates` in postgresql with rows like:

```
| id | status | person_id | modified_at      |
|----|--------|-----------|------------------|
| 1  | INFO   | 2         | 2019-11-01 10:00 |
| 1  | UPDATE | 2         | 2019-11-02 15:00 |
| 1  | DEBUG  | 2         | 2019-11-03 12:00 |
| 3  | INFO   | 4         | 2019-11-04 14:00 |
| 3  | UPDATE | 4         | 2019-11-05 16:00 |
| 5  | INFO   | 6         | 2019-11-06 08:00 |
| 5  | DEBUG  | 6         | 2019-11-07 07:00 |
```

I want to get the INFO rows that are followed by an UPDATE row:

```
| id | status | person_id | modified_at      |
|----|--------|-----------|------------------|
| 1  | INFO   | 2         | 2019-11-01 10:00 |
| 3  | INFO   | 4         | 2019-11-04 14:00 |
```

I've attempted this by doing a lead query

```
select d2.id, d2.status, d2.modified_at, d2.person_id,
lead(d2.status) over (partition by d2.id order by d2.modified_at) as next_status
from person_updates d2
where d2.status = 'INFO'
```

This returns more rows than I want.  Adding a `and d2.next_status = 'UPDATE'` throws an error.  How do I do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
select t.id, t.status, t.modified_at, t.person_id 
from (
  select *,
  lead(status) over (partition by id order by modified_at) as next_status
  from person_updates
) t 
where t.status = 'INFO' and t.next_status = 'UPDATE'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s8NxazmKSDLFqmWtR15bLG/0).
Results:

```
| id  | status | modified_at              | person_id |
| --- | ------ | ------------------------ | --------- |
| 1   | INFO   | 2019-11-01T10:00:00.000Z | 2         |
| 3   | INFO   | 2019-11-04T14:00:00.000Z | 4         |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `lead()` to get the `status` of the next record. Since window functions are not allowed in the `where` clause, you need to turn the query to a subquery, and then filter in the outer query, like so:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lead(status) over(partition by id order by modified_at) lead_status
    from person_updates t
) t
where status = 'INFO' and lead_status = 'UPDATE'
```